# I want to get after decimal value in any number

Tags: decimal

this is the random value 10.302, I want to get only after decimal value .302 and save in a variable in a flutter. please help me

I searched on youtube and google but nothing was found.

Comment: `s=10.302 afterdecimal=s-int(s)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
double number = 10.302;
double afterDecimal = number%1;
print(afterDecimal);
```

or

```
double number = 10.302;
int whole = number.toInt();
double fraction = number-whole;
print(fraction);
```

The problem is instead of `0.302` the above 2 blocks would give you something like `0.3019999999999996`.

A simple fix can be converting the number to a string and do something like this:

```
double number = 10.302;
double afterDecimal = double.parse(number.toString().split('.')[1]);
print(afterDecimal);
```

This would give an output of `302`. But if you need an output of `0.302`, you can do this:

```
double number = 10.302;
double afterDecimal = double.parse('0.' + number.toString().split('.')[1]);
print(afterDecimal);
```

This is just working around things to get the desired result. There could be better ways to get the result so, you should keep trying.